# md raid5: "no valid superblock", but mdadm --examine says everything is fine

Tags: debian, data-recovery, raid

And so, it happened: the software RAID5 on my Linux box failed somehow and now refuses to assemble.

An overview of the setup:

- headless server running **Debian Jessie 8.6** (current stable)
- custom built **Linux kernel v4.8.8** (see below), largely based on the official Debian packages - mainly done for the updated BTRFS code
- all packages are up to date as of right now, Nov. 18 2016
- four HDDs in total:

  - `/dev/sda` is partitioned for `/boot/efi`, swap and `/` (in that order)
  - `/dev/sdb` is member of the RAID (no partition table)
  - `/dev/sd[cd]` each have a single partition spanning the entire drive, with `sd[cd]1` being member of the RAID
  - `sda` is 500GB, `sd[bcd]` are 4TB disks. `sd[cd]1` are partitioned for the exact same size, `sdb` not being partitioned at all is slightly larger (wasting some space, which would otherwise be used for the partition table).
- after assembling into `/dev/md0`, the RAID is further partitioned with a single partition `/dev/md0p1` spanning the entire multi-disk, which then holds the BTRFS filesystem. (This was set up by the Debian installer, and it is too late to change.)

I recently bought a fifth disk, which was dead on arrival. I had to leave the site shortly after adding the disk to the server, so I noticed that fact not until a day or two later, but as this new disk wasn't part of the RAID yet, that should not change anything.

When I added the newly bought disk, the server was running kernel 4.8.7 and everything seemed fine. I compiled kernel version 4.8.8 and installed it, shut the server down with `systemctl poweroff`, removed the dead disk and tried rebooting. As the server is usually headless, I could only see it not coming back up after about 5 minutes of grace time. It wouldn't react to simply pressing the power button, so I cut power, added a graphics card (it has no internal one) + monitor + keyboard and was subsequently presented with `systemd`'s emergency shell.

I get the emergency shell with both the previous and the current kernel, so I assume this is either not the cause or the damage is done already. I am currently `dd`ing all three RAID disks into `/dev/null` to rule out possible physical disk failures, but as they're already over 1TB into the disks without any errors, I assume the superblock is not physically damaged on any of the disks.

---

Enough talk, let's be more specific. All following commands are issued from the emergency root shell, i.e. with a basic system running (not the initrd).

`/proc/mdstat` knows nothing about the RAID:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
unused devices: <none>
```

This is what I get with `mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md0`: (`/dev/sde` here is an external USB HDD that I used to pull out these logs)

```
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md0: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdd1 to /dev/md0: Invalid argument
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md0: Input/output error
```

... with these lines in `journalctl`:

```
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md: sdc1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md: md_import_device returned -22
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md: sdd1 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md: md_import_device returned -22
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md: bind<sdb>
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdb operational as raid disk 0
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md/raid:md0: allocated 3316kB
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md/raid:md0: not enough operational devices (2/3 failed)
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: RAID conf printout:
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel:  --- level:5 rd:3 wd:1
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel:  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdb
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md/raid:md0: failed to run raid set.
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md: pers->run() failed ...
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md: md0 stopped.
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md: unbind<sdb>
Nov 18 14:56:34 zoey kernel: md: export_rdev(sdb)
```

Oh no, the superblock is broken, and even `mdadm --assemble --force` won't assemble! Let's see what `mdadm --examine` has to say:

```
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cdab20e2:45150011:f10d83fe:f0299188
           Name : zoey:0  (local to host zoey)
  Creation Time : Fri Sep 26 17:23:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 7813840560 (3725.93 GiB 4000.69 GB)
     Array Size : 7813770240 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 196608 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=196520 sectors, after=70320 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1751c53f:c527c4cd:10e8f426:0217bf5e

    Update Time : Fri Nov 18 04:02:16 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 7fa86509 - correct
         Events : 112125

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cdab20e2:45150011:f10d83fe:f0299188
           Name : zoey:0  (local to host zoey)
  Creation Time : Fri Sep 26 17:23:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 7813902336 (3725.96 GiB 4000.72 GB)
     Array Size : 7813770240 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 196608 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=196528 sectors, after=66560 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 0c60e19b:daff087f:c1f09dbb:41bb80c3

    Update Time : Fri Nov 18 04:02:16 2016
       Checksum : 866cea0a - correct
         Events : 112125

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : cdab20e2:45150011:f10d83fe:f0299188
           Name : zoey:0  (local to host zoey)
  Creation Time : Fri Sep 26 17:23:15 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 7813902336 (3725.96 GiB 4000.72 GB)
     Array Size : 7813770240 (7451.79 GiB 8001.30 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813770240 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 196608 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=196528 sectors, after=66560 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e80a2296:dfadb7ad:e458e491:bf1d12b0

    Update Time : Fri Nov 18 04:02:16 2016
       Checksum : 72340d8d - correct
         Events : 112125

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

`mdadm --examine --scan --verbose` also seems to find all the disks just fine:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0  level=raid5 metadata=1.2 num-devices=3 UUID=cdab20e2:45150011:f10d83fe:f0299188 name=zoey:0
   devices=/dev/sdd1,/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdb
```

This line can also be found in the `mdadm.conf` that the Debian installer generated for me, back when I first installed the current OS (I didn't change this file manually, as everything was working fine for so long):

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=cdab20e2:45150011:f10d83fe:f0299188 name=zoey:0

# This file was auto-generated on Fri, 26 Sep 2014 18:10:27 +0200
# by mkconf 3.2.5-5
```

SMART also says everything is fine with all disks, with the exception of `/dev/sdc` having seen unusually high airflow temperature sometime `In_The_Past` - but the temperature problems have been resolved, and all other values (most notable reallocated / pending sectors = 0) are within acceptable margins for all drives.

I tried recreating the RAID on `device mapper` overlays over the physical block devices. However, that setup would not recognize the partition table inside the RAID, making it impossible to mount the filesystem. [You can find a typescript here.](http://pastebin.com/ZzU0CNKa)

---

And that's where I am at a loss. The entire RAID looks just fine to me, so why might the `md` driver refuse to assemble? And is there something that I could try which might improve my chances of success?

Comment: Two questions: first, are there any arrays listed in `cat /proc/mdstat`? Sometimes you'll get partially done incremental assembly, and will need to stop those before actually assembling the array; second, did you really create an array with some devices being partitions (`sd[cd]1`) and some entire disks (`sdb`)??? If not, it might just be misdetecting the device (but I think this is pretty unlikely, and you did indeed create that weird config)

Comment: @derobert First: /proc/mdstat knows nothing, added it to the question. Second: yes, this is intended; sdb really has no partition table. I planned on unifying this once the server had more free time.

Comment: That's really odd, but it seems someone has [had the problem before](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.raid/47406) (alas, without a resolution). You could try explicitly telling it the device to assemble, though I doubt it'd matter... Curious what you did with device-mapper, though, as (if done right) that *should* work, and is a reasonable way to test out what I fear might be the next step (a create with assume clean).

Comment: @derobert I added a script of the dm stuff I tried. That wouldn't yield any positive results directly, however comparing the `--examine` output before and after the recreation showed several differences that shouldn't be there, for example the newly created array having a bad block log on every device and differing data offsets ... I might just be missing some switches on that one.

Answer (score 12):

The stupidly simple solution: add `--update=devicesize` when assembling.

I have no idea how, but apparently the partition size and the size that md remembered for this drive didn't match up anymore. Cheers to the guys over at [the german ubuntuusers forum](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/bekomme-array-nicht-re-assembled/) who painstakingly solved their case with manual hex editing before finally finding the correct switch to `mdadm`.

Comment: I'd suggest reporting a bug—mdadm really ought to notice that and tell you.

Comment: I shrunk my ext4 root partition (by running `resize2fs` from initramfs), then resized using `mdadm --grow` (also from initramfs) and then manually updated the partition tables af my raid1 array and hoped for the best but it didn't boot and I got `<device> does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!`, running this appears to have fixed it, many thanks!